# How do I create a DVD from an MP4 file using Windows DVD Maker?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, mp4

I'm trying to create a DVD from an MP4 file using Windows DVD Maker (on Windows 7) but when doing so I get the error that the file type is not supported and cannot be imported. What is the easiest way to resolve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows DVD maker is not capable to handle .mp4 files  unless you install a codec package like [Haali Media Splitter](http://haali.su/mkv/).

But a no-brainer solution is [DVDstyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/)

> DVDStyler is a cross-platform free DVD authoring application for the creation of professional-looking DVDs. It allows [...] burning of video files on DVD that can be played practically on any standalone DVD player [...]

- burns DVD video
- re-encodes .mp4 an many [other file formats](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/components/content/81)
- has a [beginners guide](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/documents?id=70)
- [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/dvdstyler_portable) is available

  [image]

Comment: Be careful with DVDStyler, it includes annoying adware.

Comment: @DanaHolt Thanks for noticing it. Therefore I recommend the [portable version from portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/dvdstyler_portable) which explicitly hasn't this issue

Answer (score 3):

I do not use that SW, but I would use [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) which is free and opensource, to load the video and then save using main menu *Auto/Optical Disc/DVD* which should automatically set correct settings for export. Then save video using menu File/Save/Save video. Just make sure, that the output video has an extension (Avidemux sometimes forgets to add it) - it should be *.mpg or *.vob as I know.

[image: Avidemux main window screenshot]

Windows DVD Maker should be able to load the exported file without problems.

Comment: Dead link. [need more characters]

Comment: link updated :-)

Answer (score 1):

I converted my .mp4 file to .wmv, which is Windows-native format.  Windows DVD Maker seems to like that.  I carried out the conversion with RealPlayer (circa 2015), which allows you to perform conversions on Movies and Music from one format to another.  Just get the basic free Real Player and convert your .mp4 to .wmv from the Tools menu, then load that into Windows DVD Maker and it should work.

If you can't load the .mp4 file for some reason, then you can load a codec pack which I have found can help.  I used K-Lite Codec Pack, which is free.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Robert Casey's answer, I converted the MP4 file to an AVI file using [SimpleVideoConverter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svideoconverter/), which is a Java based wrapper for [MEncoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder). You could also convert the format to any other one Windows DVD maker supports.

[image: screenshot of file types Microsoft Windows DVD Maker support]

Answer (score 0):

I used [Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com/download?id=FreemakeVideoConverter.exe) - it can convert a bunch of formats to DVD (or DVD ISO as well). I tried the solutions listed above but they meant I had to fiddle with video bitrates etc. Freemake does all the calculations for you. The only thing is it adds a "freemake" splash screen to the beginning and end of the DVD.

DVDstyler didn't seem to to work for me when I tried it.