# How can I create a video dvd from an mp4 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

How can I create a video dvd from an mp4 on Windows 10?

I used windows live movie maker to create a movie and it exported it to an mp4 file. Now I'd like to burn it onto a dvd that could play on a DVD player.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/392227/how-do-i-create-a-dvd-from-an-mp4-file-using-windows-dvd-maker

Comment: http://www.techisky.com/software/windows-dvd-maker-for-windows-10.html

Comment: wondershare doesn't seem to have a nice reputation either https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/wondershare.com | https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/?p=2680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider one of these 3rd party freeware

DVD Styler
http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/

DVD Flick
http://www.dvdflick.net/features.php

They were once featured in LifeHacker as well.

Comment: 3rd party software recommendations are not considered as answers here on SU.

Comment: @Moab, I thought we can't ask for software recommendations. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27612486#27612486 - although the answer is poor quality as it's basically link only!

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. Provide more than just a link, eg some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: @Dave you can ask but question might get closed, this question did not specifically ask for software recommendations, it asked "how can I"